# Is it possible to change UIDatePickerModeCountDownTimer labels

Tags: objective-c, uidatepicker

I've created a UIDatePicker and set his mode to UIDatePickerModeCountDownTimer and I wanted to know if it's possible to change the text of his default labels (Hours, min)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### YES, you can

> These two labels (hours, min) basically subview of UIDatePicker. So, you can access
>   these label by accessing subviews of UIDatePicker and then customise
>   as you want.

**Add these three line in viewDidAppear method**

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
     NSInteger totalSubView = [[datePicker.subviews[0] subviews] count];
     ((UILabel *)[[datePicker.subviews[0] subviews] objectAtIndex:(totalSubView-2)]).text = @"hr";
     ((UILabel *)[[datePicker.subviews[0] subviews] objectAtIndex:(totalSubView-1)]).text = @"m";
}
```

> Note:- every time you change the value of UIDatePicker these label are
>   reset. So, you need call these three line every time when value of
>   UIDatePicker changed.

[image]